# How to hide a gmail password used by nodemailer to push on a public github repository?

Tags: node.js, express, github, passwords, nodemailer

I need to hide a username and password used by nodemailer to be able to push on a public repo.

For now, I am forced to do a push on github without the file containing this info; this is a contact file that creates an object "transporter", which itself contains this private information ...

Then, my app on the server being connected to its github repo for a continuous deployment, it crashes the deployment because this file becomes missing ...

I have to re-do a push, but this time directly to the server, so with this famous contact file to restore the site.

So, the continuous deployment becomes useless !

Besides, as a result, I can't version this file !

Answer (score 2):

Either use a configuration file, add this to your .gitignore and then add the file to the server manually once or use environmental variables/ command line arguments.

You can access environmental variables using node.js in the format:

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```

or

```
process.argv
```

is an array of command line arguments in node.js

Comment: I forgot to say that I use Express (so I add the express tag), and I tried to integrate a configuration file but nothing works; So I loaded the dotenv module, and the same result: maybe I do not load it in the correct order or with the correct syntax? But I also read that dotenv can not be used for production, so I do not know what to do ...

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thanks! NOw I just need to go back and delete the info from my git history..

Answer (score 0):

Check with your hosting service for a way around using the password. For example, with AWS, you register a secure email address (I've used a gmail address), and then you use a security key, which you add the the server file like this:

```
//Sends mail with submission forms
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    rateLimit: 5
  }));

app.get('/send-mail',function(req,res){
  const mailOptions = {
   to : req.query.to,
   from: req.query.to,
   subject : "New email subject",
   text : "New email text"
  }
```

Note that I am sending from the secure email address to itself. I then forward from that address to wherever I want the email to go. You could instead add another secure address, but AWS will not send to an address that is not registered.